# Is it safe to turn off security.ssl.enable_ocsp_stapling

Tags: firefox, ssl

I am facing a `PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR` problem while using firefox via a proxy.
It fail to setup security connection.
I found a solution [here](https://cheapsslsecurity.com/blog/troubleshoot-secure-connection-failed-error-firefox/) and it do alleviate this problem.

But it doesn't tell me why. Will it be risky to turn off `security.ssl.enable_ocsp_stapling`. What actually am I doing?